# Javascript Background color switching

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use javascript to control the background color of a form element, what I have so far:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('option.POIs').click(function() {
        $(this)
           .css('background-color','#EE178C')

        });
    });

    </script>
```

It works well, however I would like for it to toggle between to different colors. Default color would be #FFFFFF and the other would be #EE178C. So when the page loads the bg color is #FFFFFF when I click on the item the bg changes to #EE178C, and if I click on it again it goes back to #FFFFF.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI

```
.POIs{background:#fff}.POIs.toggle{background:#EE178C}
```

script

```
 $('option.POIs').click(function() {$(this).toggleClass('toggle')})
```

Comment: glad we agree :) @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `:focus` pseudo-selector for this in your CSS. No javascript required.

Comment: Not if they want to toggle the color without losing focus, which seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var isDefaultColor = true;
var defaultColor = '#FFFFF';
var alternateColor = '#EE178C';

if(isDefaultColor)
  $(this).css('background-color', alternateColor);
else
  $(this).css('background-color', defaultColor);

isDefaultColor = !isDefaultColor;
```

Comment: Unreliable, as I found out the hard way. Some browsers change your input to `rgb()` format. I suggest using a variable `isColor1` and toggling it when the background colour is toggled.